# Need help in c++ multilevel inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, c++17

I am trying to build a multilevel inheritance for trees and their nodes. So I start with a BaseNode, then I create a BSTNode which inherits from the BaseNode, then I create AVLNode which inherits from the BSTNode. Each of these classes has member functions that need to be overloaded, but they need to return their respective class. So if I call AVLNode-> to insert(1) then this should return a pointer of type AVLNode, while BSTNode->insert(1) should return a pointer of type BSTNode.  Moreover, each of these Nodes can store multiple types as keys, for example, we can have a BSTNode with the key of type int, and have another BSTNode with the key of type long. These nodes will be part of another set of classes that will represent the respective trees.

```
class BaseNode {
    T key;
    BaseNode<T>* insert();
}
class BSTNode: public BaseNode {
    BSTNode<T>* insert(); // extending the BaseNode insert
}
class AVLNode: public BSTNode {
   AVLNode<T>* insert(); // extending the BSTNode insert
}

class BST {
    BSTNode<T>* root;
}

class AVL {
    AVLNode<T> *root;
}
```

I have tried looking at CRTP, but it only works for 1 level of inheritance. I need some pointers (pun intended) on how to solve this or whether it can it solved using C++.

This is my code:

```
template<typename T>
class AbstractBinaryTreeNode {
    protected:
        T key;
        int counter;
        AbstractBinaryTreeNode<T> *left, *right, *parent;
    public:
        virtual void inorder_print();
        virtual void pre_order_print();
        virtual void post_order_print();
        virtual void print_key();

        virtual T get_key();
        virtual void set_key(T key);

        virtual AbstractBinaryTreeNode<T>* get_parent();
        virtual AbstractBinaryTreeNode<T>* get_left();
        virtual AbstractBinaryTreeNode<T>* get_right();
        virtual void set_parent(AbstractBinaryTreeNode<T>* node);
        virtual void set_left(AbstractBinaryTreeNode<T>* node);
        virtual void set_right(AbstractBinaryTreeNode<T>* node);

        virtual bool check_ri();
        virtual AbstractBinaryTreeNode* search(T key);
        virtual AbstractBinaryTreeNode* insert(T key);
        virtual AbstractBinaryTreeNode* remove();

        virtual ~AbstractBinaryTreeNode() {};
};

template<typename T>
class BinaryTreeNode: public AbstractBinaryTreeNode<T> {
    public:
        void inorder_print() ;
        void pre_order_print() ;
        void post_order_print() ;
        void print_key() ;
        T get_key() ;
        void set_key(T key) ;
        BinaryTreeNode<T>* get_parent() ;
        BinaryTreeNode<T>* get_left() ;
        BinaryTreeNode<T>* get_right() ;
        void set_parent(BinaryTreeNode<T>* node);
        void set_left(BinaryTreeNode<T>* node);
        void set_right(BinaryTreeNode<T>* node);
};

class BSTNode: public BinaryTreeNode<T> {
    public:
        BSTNode(T key);
        
        bool check_ri() ;
        BSTNode<T>* insert(T key);
        BSTNode<T>* search(T key);
        BSTNode<T>* remove();
        BSTNode<T>* next_larger();
        BSTNode<T>* find_min();
};
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘BinaryTreeNode<int>*’ to ‘BSTNode<int>*’
```

EDIT: After thinking, I looked into interface implementation separation but now the overloading is not working right.

binary_tree_node.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include"Impl/binary_tree_node_impl.hpp"

template<typename T>
class BinaryTreeNode{
    public:
        BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, BinaryTreeNode<T>>* impl;
        BinaryTreeNode();
        BinaryTreeNode(T key);

        virtual void inorder_print();
        virtual void pre_order_print();
        virtual void post_order_print();
        void print_key() ;
        virtual T get_key() ;
        void set_key(T key);

        BinaryTreeNode<T>* get_parent();
        BinaryTreeNode<T>* get_left();
        BinaryTreeNode<T>* get_right();
        
        virtual void set_parent(void* node);
        virtual void set_left(void* node);
        virtual void set_right(void* node);

        virtual bool check_ri() = 0;
};

#include"binary_tree_node.tpp"
```

binary_tree_node.tpp

template

```
BinaryTreeNode<T>::BinaryTreeNode() {
    this->impl = new BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, BinaryTreeNode<T>>();
}

template<typename T>
BinaryTreeNode<T>::BinaryTreeNode(T key) {
    this->impl = new BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, BinaryTreeNode<T>>(this);
}

template<typename T>
BinaryTreeNode<T>* BinaryTreeNode<T>::get_parent() {
    return this->impl->get_parent();
}

template<typename T>
BinaryTreeNode<T>* BinaryTreeNode<T>::get_left() {
    return this->impl->get_left();
}

template<typename T>
BinaryTreeNode<T>* BinaryTreeNode<T>::get_right() {
    return this->impl->get_right();
}

template<typename T>
void BinaryTreeNode<T>::set_parent(void* node) {
    this->impl->set_parent((BinaryTreeNode<T>*) node);
}

template<typename T>
void BinaryTreeNode<T>::set_left(void* node) {
    this->impl->set_left((BinaryTreeNode<T>*)node);
}

template<typename T>
void BinaryTreeNode<T>::set_right(void* node) {
    this->impl->set_right((BinaryTreeNode<T>*)node);
}

template<typename T>
void BinaryTreeNode<T>::print_key() {
    this->impl->print_key();
}

template<typename T>
void BinaryTreeNode<T>::pre_order_print() {
    this->impl->pre_order_print();
}

template<typename T>
void BinaryTreeNode<T>::inorder_print() {
    this->impl->inorder_print();
}

template<typename T>
void BinaryTreeNode<T>::post_order_print() {
    this->impl->post_order_print();
}

template<typename T>
T BinaryTreeNode<T>::get_key() {
    return this->impl->get_key();
}

template<typename T>
void BinaryTreeNode<T>::set_key(T key) {
    this->impl->set_key(key);
}
```

binary_tree_impl.hpp

```
#pragma once

template<typename T, class NodeType>
class BinaryTreeImpl {
    public:
        NodeType *root;

        BinaryTreeImpl() {};
        BinaryTreeImpl(T key) {};
        
        virtual void inorder_print();
        virtual void pre_order_print();
        virtual void post_order_print();

        virtual bool check_ri() = 0;
        virtual NodeType* insert(T key) = 0;
        virtual NodeType* remove(T key) = 0;
        virtual NodeType* search(T key) = 0;
};

#include"binary_tree_impl.tpp"
```

binary_tree_impl.tpp

```
template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeImpl<T, NodeType>::inorder_print() {
    if(this->root) 
        this->root->inorder_print();
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeImpl<T, NodeType>::pre_order_print() {
    if (this->root)
        this->root->pre_order_print();
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeImpl<T, NodeType>::post_order_print() {
    if(this->root) 
        this->root->post_order_print();
}
```

binary_tree_node_impl.hpp

```
# pragma once


template<typename T, class NodeType>
class BinaryTreeNodeImpl {
    public:
        T key;
        int counter;
        NodeType *node;
        NodeType *left, *right, *parent; 
    
        BinaryTreeNodeImpl() {};
        BinaryTreeNodeImpl(T key, NodeType* node);

        virtual bool check_ri() {};
        virtual void inorder_print();
        virtual void pre_order_print();
        virtual void post_order_print();
        
        T get_key();
        void set_key(T key);
        void print_key();

        virtual NodeType* get_parent();
        virtual NodeType* get_left();
        virtual NodeType* get_right();

        virtual void set_parent(void* node);
        virtual void set_left(void* node);
        virtual void set_right(void* node);
};

#include "binary_tree_node_impl.tpp"
```

binary_tree_node_impl.tpp

template<

```
typename T, class NodeType>
BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::BinaryTreeNodeImpl(T key, NodeType* node) {
    this->key = key;
    this->node = node; 
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::get_parent() {
    return this->parent;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::get_left() {
    return this->left;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::get_right() {
    return this->right;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::set_parent(void* node) {
    this->parent = (NodeType*)node;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::set_left(void* node) {
    this->left = (NodeType*)node;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::set_right(void* node) {
    this->right = (NodeType*)node;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::print_key() {
    std::cout<<this->key<<std::endl;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::pre_order_print() {
    for(int i = 0; i < this->counter; i++)
        std::cout<<this->key<<" ";
    if (this->left)
        this->left->pre_order_print();
    if(this->right)
        this->right->pre_order_print();
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::inorder_print() {
    if (this->left)
        this->left->inorder_print();
    for(int i = 0; i < this->counter; i++)
        std::cout<<this->key<<" ";
    if(this->right)
        this->right->inorder_print();
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::post_order_print() {
    if (this->left)
        this->left->pre_order_print();
    if(this->right)
        this->right->pre_order_print();
    for(int i = 0; i < this->counter; i++)
        std::cout<<this->key<<" ";
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
T BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::get_key() {
    return this->key;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
void BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::set_key(T key) {
    this->key = key;
}
```

binary_tree.hpp

```
#pragma once 

#include"binary_tree_node.hpp"
#include"Impl/binary_tree_impl.hpp"

template<typename T>
class BinaryTree {
    public:
        BinaryTreeImpl<T, BSTNode<T>> *impl;
        BinaryTree() {};
        BinaryTree(T key);
        virtual void inorder_print();
        virtual void pre_order_print();
        virtual void post_order_print();

        virtual bool check_ri() = 0;
        virtual BinaryTreeNode<T>* insert(T key) = 0;
        virtual BinaryTreeNode<T>* remove(T key) = 0;
        virtual BinaryTreeNode<T>* search(T key) = 0;
};

#include"binary_tree.tpp"
```

binary_tree.tpp

```
template<typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::inorder_print() {
    this->impl->inorder_print();
}

template<typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::pre_order_print() {
    this->impl->pre_order_print();
}

template<typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::post_order_print() {
    this->impl->post_order_print();
}
```

bst_impl.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include"../../binary_tree/Impl/binary_tree_impl.hpp"

template<typename T, class NodeType>
class BSTImpl: public BinaryTreeImpl<T, NodeType> {
    private:
        NodeType *root;     
    public:
        BSTImpl() {};
        BSTImpl(T key);

        bool check_ri();
        NodeType* insert(T key) override;
        NodeType* search(T key) override;
        NodeType* remove(T key) override;

        ~BSTImpl();
};

#include"bst_impl.tpp"
```

bst_impl.tpp

```
template<typename T, class NodeType>
BSTImpl<T, NodeType>::BSTImpl(T key) {
    if (this->root == nullptr)
        this->root = new NodeType(key);
    else
        this->root->insert(key);
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BSTImpl<T, NodeType>::insert(T key) {
    if (this->root == nullptr)
        this->root = new NodeType(key);
    else
        this->root->insert(key);
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
bool BSTImpl<T, NodeType>::check_ri() {
    if (this->root) {
        return this->root->check_ri();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BSTImpl<T, NodeType>::search(T key) {
    if (this->root)
        return this->root->search(key);
    else
        return nullptr;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BSTImpl<T, NodeType>::remove(T key) {
    if(this->root){
        NodeType *temp = this->root->search(key);
        if (temp == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        else if (temp == this->root) {
            NodeType *node = new NodeType(0);
            node->set_left(this->root);
            this->root->set_parent(node);
            NodeType* deleted = this->root->remove();
            this->root = node->get_left();
            if(this->root) 
                this->root->set_parent(nullptr);
            return deleted;
        } else {
            NodeType *deleted = temp->remove();
            this->check_ri();
            return deleted;
        }
    }
}
```

bst_node_impl.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include"../../binary_tree/Impl/binary_tree_node_impl.hpp"

template<typename T, class NodeType>
class BSTNodeImpl: public BinaryTreeNodeImpl<T, NodeType> {
    public:
        T key;
        int counter;
        NodeType *node;
        NodeType *left, *right, *parent;

        BSTNodeImpl(T key, NodeType* node);
        bool check_ri();
        T get_key();

        NodeType* insert(T key);
        NodeType* search(T key);
        NodeType* remove();
        NodeType* next_larger();
        NodeType* find_min();
};

#include"bst_node_impl.tpp"
```

bst_node_impl.tpp

```
template<typename T, class NodeType>
BSTNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::BSTNodeImpl(T key, NodeType* node) {
    this->right = nullptr;
    this->left = nullptr;
    this->parent = nullptr;
    this->key = key;
    this->counter = 1;
    this->node = node;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BSTNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::find_min() {
    return this->left ? this->left->find_min(): this->node;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BSTNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::next_larger() {
    if (this->right)
        return this->right->find_min();
    else {
        NodeType *temp = this->node;
        while(temp->get_parent() && temp == temp->get_parent()->get_right()) {
            temp = temp->get_parent();
        }
        return temp->get_parent();
    }
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BSTNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::remove() {
    if (this->left == nullptr || this->right == nullptr) {
        if(this->node == this->parent->get_left()) {
            this->parent->set_left(this->left ? this->left : this->right);
            if (this->parent->get_left()) {
                this->parent->get_left()->set_parent(this->parent);
            }
        } else {
            this->parent->set_right(this->left ? this->left : this->right);
            if (this->parent->get_right()) {
                this->parent->get_right()->set_parent(this->parent);
            }
        }
        return this->node;
    } else {
        NodeType *temp = this->next_larger();
        T temp_key = temp->get_key(); 
        temp->set_key(this->key);
        this->key = temp_key;
        return temp->remove();
    }        
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BSTNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::search(T key) {
    if (this->key == key)
        return this->node;
    else if (this->key > key)
        return this->left ? this->left->search(key) : nullptr;
    else if (this->key < key)
        return this->right ? this->right->search(key) : nullptr;
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
NodeType* BSTNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::insert(T key) {
    if (this->key == key) {
        this->counter++;
        return this->node;
    }
    else if (this->key > key) {
        if (this->left == nullptr) {
            this->left = new NodeType(key);
            this->left = this->node;
            return this->node;
        } else {
            this->left->insert(key);
        }
    } else {
        if (this->right == nullptr) {
            this->right = new NodeType(key);
            this->right = this->node;
            return this->node;
        } else {
            this->right->insert(key);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
bool BSTNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::check_ri() {
    if (this->left == nullptr && this->right == nullptr)
        return true;
    if (this->left && this->left->get_key() > this->key)
        return false;
    if (this->right && this->right->get_key() < this->key)
        return false;
    if (this->left && this->right)
        return this->left->check_ri() && this->right->check_ri();
    else if (this->left)
        return this->left->check_ri();
    else
        return this->right->check_ri();
}

template<typename T, class NodeType>
T BSTNodeImpl<T, NodeType>::get_key() {
    return this->key;
}
```

bst_node.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include"Impl/bst_node_impl.hpp"
#include"../binary_tree/binary_tree_node.hpp"

template<typename T>
class BSTNode: public BinaryTreeNode<T> {
    public:
        BSTNodeImpl<T, BSTNode<T>>* impl;
        BSTNode();
        BSTNode(T key);
        bool check_ri() override;

        T get_key() override;

        void inorder_print();
        void pre_order_print();
        void post_order_print();

        BSTNode<T>* get_left();
        BSTNode<T>* get_right();
        BSTNode<T>* get_parent();

        BSTNode<T>* insert(T key);
        BSTNode<T>* search(T key);
        BSTNode<T>* remove();
        BSTNode<T>* next_larger();
        BSTNode<T>* find_min();

        void set_parent(void* node) override;
        void set_left(void* node) override;
        void set_right(void* node) override;
};

#include "bst_node.tpp"
```

bst_node.tpp

```
template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>::BSTNode(T key) {
    this->impl = new BSTNodeImpl<T, BSTNode<T>>(key, this);
    this->impl->get_key();
}

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BSTNode<T>::find_min() {
    return (BSTNode<T>*)this->impl->find_min();
}

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BSTNode<T>::next_larger() {
    return (BSTNode<T>*)this->impl->next_larger();
}

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BSTNode<T>::remove() {
    return (BSTNode<T>*)this->impl->remove();
}

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BSTNode<T>::search(T key) {
    return (BSTNode<T>*)this->impl->search(key);
}

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BSTNode<T>::insert(T key) {
    return (BSTNode<T>*)this->impl->insert(key);
}

template<typename T>
bool BSTNode<T>::check_ri() {
    return this->impl->check_ri();
}   

template<typename T>
void BSTNode<T>::set_left(void* node) {
    this->impl->set_left((BSTNode<T>*) node);
} 

template<typename T>
void BSTNode<T>::set_parent(void* node) {
    this->impl->set_parent((BSTNode<T>*) node);
}

template<typename T>
void BSTNode<T>::set_right(void* node) {
    this->impl->set_right((BSTNode<T>*) node);
}

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BSTNode<T>::get_right() {
    return (BSTNode<T>*)this->impl->get_right();
} 

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BSTNode<T>::get_left() {
    return (BSTNode<T>*)this->impl->get_left();
} 

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BSTNode<T>::get_parent() {
    return (BSTNode<T>*)this->impl->get_parent();
}

template<typename T>
T BSTNode<T>::get_key() {
    return this->impl->get_key();
}

template<typename T>
void BSTNode<T>::pre_order_print() {
    this->impl->pre_order_print();
}

template<typename T>
void BSTNode<T>::inorder_print() {
    this->impl->inorder_print();
}

template<typename T>
void BSTNode<T>::post_order_print() {
    this->impl->post_order_print();
}
```

bst.hpp

```
#pragma once


#include"../binary_tree/binary_tree.hpp"
#include"Impl/bst_impl.hpp"
#include"bst_node.hpp"

template<typename T>
class BST: public BinaryTree<T> {
    public:
        BSTImpl<T, BSTNode<T>> *impl;
        BST();
        BST(T key);
        bool check_ri();
        BSTNode<T>* insert(T key) override;
        BSTNode<T>* search(T key) override;
        BSTNode<T>* remove(T key) override;
};

#include "bst.tpp"
```

bst.tpp

```
template<typename T>
BST<T>::BST(){
    this->impl = new BSTImpl<T, BSTNode<T>>();
}

template<typename T>
BST<T>::BST(T key){
    this->impl = new BSTImpl<T, BSTNode<T>>(key);
}

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BST<T>::insert(T key) {
    return this->impl->insert(key);
}

template<typename T>
bool BST<T>::check_ri() {
    return this->impl->check_ri();
}

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BST<T>::search(T key) {
    return this->impl->search(key);
}

template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BST<T>::remove(T key) {
    return this->impl->remove(key);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include"bst_node.hpp"
#include"bst.hpp"
#include"../utils.hpp"

int  main () {
    std::vector<int> array = get_random_array<int>(10, 100);
    BST<int> *bst = new BST<int>();
    for(auto item: array) {
        bst->insert(item);
        bst->inorder_print();
        bst->check_ri();
    }

}
```

I get seg fault when I run it.

Comment: C++ has the concept of [covariant return types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type). If `BSTNode`'s override of `insert` returns a `BSTNode<T>*` but `BaseNode` expects a `BaseNode<T>*`, that's fine as long as `BSTNode<T>` publically inherits from `BaseNode<T>`.

Comment: What's your actual issue?  You don't actually need any polymorphism here, so the snippet you posted already does what you want (outside of the missing `template <typename T>` on each of your class templates).

Comment: Can you make as much of your sample code as you can compile?  And then point out where it doesn't work or what is missing?  Your high level description is confusing, as I cannot tell what doesn't work.  I mean, your code has piles of obvious problems in it, but I don't know if you are only missing something obvious or not.  Like, `BaseNode` obviously should be a template; I see a dozen problems that obvious to me.  Is one of them your stumbling block?  I have no idea.  **try** and tell or show us what failed.  (Also include the high level description)

Comment: Added the actual code

Comment: You are missing `template<typename T>` before `class BSTNode` definition. Once added, the example you show [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/1WG7hc).

Comment: Note however that `void set_parent(BinaryTreeNode<T>* node);` in `BinaryTreeNode` does not override `virtual void set_parent(AbstractBinaryTreeNode<T>* node);` in the base class. Rather, it's an independent, unrelated overload. Taking a step back, that virtual function says that every tree node type should accept as parent a pointer to any other node type, not necessarily the same type - this doesn't make sense unless you actually want to support trees that combine nodes of different types.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik When I initialize the tree, I get a noncompatible pointers compiler error. I was looking into interface implementation separation to solve but there I am calling the parent implementation not the child's.

Comment: Well, you need to post code that actually fails; it's kinda pointless to post code that compiles successfully, then complain about an error that the code shown doesn't in fact demonstrate. In other words, post a [mcve]. That said, as I already mentioned, your design doesn't make sense, no offense intended. You don't want `virtual AbstractNode::set_parent(AbstractNode*)` unless you expect every node type to accept any other node type as a parent.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Added the recent code.

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing the uninitialized variable `BSTImpl::root`. You seem to assume it would be automatically initialized to `nullptr` - it is not.

Comment: That are a lot of files with a lot of code. Isn't it possible to reduce it to a [mcve] with focus on minimal?